# Terraform Azure database module - unknown resource

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, terraform

trying to use the database module from: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/Azure/database/azurerm/1.0.1

i have made objects in Azure from my workstation, so the basics are all in place.

I copied the main / variables / outputs files to a folder (sql) and then used the example (below) to call it.

```
    # Configure the Azure Provider
    provider "azurerm" {}

    module "sql-database" {
         source              = "./sql"
         resource_group_name = "myapp"
         location            = "westus"
         db_name             = "mydatabase"
         sql_admin_username  = "mradministrator"
         sql_password        = "P@ssw0rd12345!"

    tags = {
         environment = "dev"
         costcenter  = "it"
         }
    }
```

When i run terraform init, i get the below error, any idea what im doing wrong?

```
PS C:\GITHUB\terraform_azure\app> terraform init
Initializing modules...
- module.sql-database
Error getting plugins: 9 problems:

- output 'sql_server_name': unknown resource 'azurerm_sql_server.server' 
referenced in variable azurerm_sql_server.server.name
- output 'sql_server_location': unknown resource 'azurerm_sql_server.server' 
referenced in variable azurerm_sql_server.server.location
- output 'sql_server_version': unknown resource 'azurerm_sql_server.server' 
referenced in variable azurerm_sql_server.server.version
- output 'sql_server_fqdn': unknown resource 'azurerm_sql_server.server' 
referenced in variable azurerm_sql_server.server.fully_qualified_domain_name
- output 'connection_string': unknown resource 'azurerm_sql_server.server' 
referenced in variable azurerm_sql_server.server.administrator_login_password
- output 'connection_string': unknown resource 'azurerm_sql_server.server' 
referenced in variable azurerm_sql_server.server.fully_qualified_domain_name
- output 'connection_string': unknown resource 'azurerm_sql_database.db' 
referenced in variable azurerm_sql_database.db.name
- output 'connection_string': unknown resource 'azurerm_sql_server.server' 
referenced in variable azurerm_sql_server.server.administrator_login
- output 'database_name': unknown resource 'azurerm_sql_database.db' 
referenced in variable azurerm_sql_database.db.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Configure the Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {}

module "sql-database" {
  version = "1.0.1"
  source  = "./sql"
  resource_group_name = "myapp"
  location            = "westus"
  db_name             = "mydatabase"
  sql_admin_username  = "mradministrator"
  sql_password        = "P@ssw0rd12345!"

  tags = {
    environment = "dev"
    costcenter  = "it"
  }
}
```

Updated the main file to above and it worked (AKA I added the version number.. Not sure why that made it work! I dont see anything in the database Main file saying anything about version.. but that got it the init completing!

Comment: This isn't helpful for anyone other than users of your SQL server module. You should probably have closed the question instead of self answering.

Comment: The `version` you are supplying is not one of the allowed values according to the documentation (i.e. `2.0` or `12.0` (default)). Maybe this holds a clue to what really is going on?